# Custom Paging asp.net using PagedList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, pagination, pagedlist

I started to learn ASP.NET this semester. We got an assignment to make a simple 3x2 gallery and also there we need to display pagination in a specified way (sorry for my English ).

We are using ASP.NET MVC 4 , the C# one and the pagination should look like:

**Prev 1 2 3 4 5 ... 20 Next**

Using pagedlist, I was able to display this:

**Prev 1 2 3 4 5 ... Next**

I need some help to display the **20** . Please help me.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), new PagedListRenderOptions {

        DisplayLinkToPreviousPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
        DisplayLinkToLastPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Never,
        MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 5,
        LinkToNextPageFormat = "Next",
        LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "Prev"

})
```

**Index method in controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(int ? page)
    {
        return View(db.Galleries.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1,6));
    }
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using PagedListPager from https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList? 
The options are described in the source code, at [PagedListRenderOptions.cs](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList.Mvc/PagedListRenderOptions.cs).

It looks like you shouold be able to say something like this, to get a link to the last page that only contains the page number.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), new PagedListRenderOptions {
    DisplayLinkToLastPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
    LinkToLastPageFormat = "{0}"
})
```

Comment: I tried that, bu then it displayed

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10... >> 20

the "20" is displayed at the very end. It must come before the >>.

Comment: From what I can see in the source code, you then have to either fix the display order in CSS, or change the source code of the PagedList. Right now it renders the "page links", then the "next" link, and finally the "last" link. It doesn't look like you can customize this order.